# APK's Supported Device List Does Not Match Google Play

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I have an issue where I have uploaded a new app and APK on Google Play and certain devices, such as TF201 (Asus tablet) are unable to install the app due to an indication that "This app is incompatible with your" device message.

However, this app manifest is very similar to another app that is supported on these devices and I have used, for example,

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

and other similar uses-feature tags to ensure that telephony and other similar features are not required for the app.

The interesting/frustrating part is that in the Developer Console, the APK's Supported Devices lists all but 309 devices and most tablets, such as the TF201 as being compatible. Yet it is not available when searching the store (yes, the app is available in search and has been for several days on other devices).

Google indicates that the APK's Supported Devices list should be checked for app filtering (http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#google-play
):
Confirm the app's filtering
After you've uploaded the app to the Developer Console, check the APK's Supported Devices list to make sure that the app is not filtered from tablet devices that you want to target.

What should I do to make this app available on Google Play so that it matches the device list shown in the Developer Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your **uses-sdk** includes the **android:targetSdkVersion** with a value of **11** or higher.
Seems Google added this criteria (without telling anyone directly) when they release the new version of Google Play.

The [Tablet App Quality Checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#google-play) under **8. Target Android versions properly**
now states that

> a. targetSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher (14 or higher is recommended)

It seems that this only applies to updates/new-releases as previous apps which lack this seems unaffected. The Developer Console also doesn't seem to be "aware" of this requirement as it clearly states xlarge devices as supported.

Comment: This seems likely to be the issue that I am having. Unfortunately, the code I inherited did not specify a targetSdkVersion and adding a value of 11 or higher has broken several things in the app, so I will not be able to confirm this until I can correct some of these issues and re-submit. I really appreciate your feedback on this and I think it is leading me down the right path.

Comment: You don't need to publish the app to verify it, just make sure that when you upload the new apk, that in the "details" you get before you save the apk (publish /save draft) that "Supported screens" includes xlarge.

Comment: thanks so much! I wanted to confirm before accepting, but it does appear as you suggest that if you upload a new apk and the Supported screens lists xlarge you will be okay. Just published a version and tablets are supported again.